# Any way to get a data extension row by id using the Rest API

Tags: marketing-cloud

I did not see anything in the documentation that says we can grab a data extension by id. Do I have to use Soap to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be some undocumented routes, but anything undocumented has a lesser chance of being supported in the long run.  Version 2 of the API is coming out later this year and next, which will have most of the necessary REST routes and be easier to use.  If you look at the Network tab (in chrome) for the Marketing Cloud, you may be able to observe some routes being used that do what you need. ie. in the Email app, grabbing the fields of DE: /internal/v1/customobjects/<guid>/fields/  or the actual data: internal/v1/customObjectData/<guid>/?$page=1&$pagesize=200

You may find a "rowset" route if you query this: /data/v1/rest

Comment: Where is the network tab in the marketing cloud?

Comment: Sorry, in a browser like Chrome, open Developer Tools.  In the network tab you can view network traffic.  Using an app or chrome extension like Postman, you can make REST calls.

Comment: I don't think "internal" routes are publicly available, and are only used for the UI.